# how to use Error: transliterator_transliterate() with phpunit on wercker?

Tags: php, laravel, pear, transliteration, wercker

I'm using box: `php:7.1-fpm` in wercker
In my code I'm using function transliterator_transliterate()

It works locally and on the server, however when running tests in wercker it is displaying error

```
Error: Call to undefined function \Utils\transliterator_transliterate()
```

Mo code is:

```
$string = transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [\u0080-\u7fff] remove', $string);
```

I already tried these solutions.

```
1. \transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [\u0080-\u7fff] remove', $string);

 2. added pear and php5-intl to wercker config

    - script:
        name: add pear
        code: |
          sudo apt-get install -y php-pear php5-intl
          # Configure PEAR
          pear config-set php_ini /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
          pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Is there any method to check if pear is working properly or solution to make 
`transliterator_transliterate()` working?

Comment: Is your test environment also running PHP 7? `php5-intl` is for PHP 5.

Comment: are you sure? In a few places I found recommendation of adding php5-intl
I'm adding in the same way also other packages, for mysql.

If not php5-intl, what I should add? php-intl is not working. Another option php56-intl is not making any change